# is "wie geschnitten Brot" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, idiom

I came across this idiom in a sentence similar to this one:

> das iPhone verkauft sich wie geschnitten Brot

*geschnitten Brot*  sounds wrong to me, shouldn't the adjective be declined?

I searched the alternative form "wie geschnittenes Brot" and based on google results it is 4 times less popular.

Comment: It should, but it’s an idiom. I used to cringe whenever I read or heard “[Butter bei die Fische](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=butter+bei+die+fische&bool=relevanz&suchspalte[]=rart_ou&suchspalte[]=bsp_ou)” or “[Nachtigall, ich hör dir trapsen](http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=nachtigall+ich+hör+dir+trapsen&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte[]=rart_ou&suchspalte[]=bsp_ou)”.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking you are right to doubt the grammatical correctness of this term. According to all applicable grammatical rules, this should read "wie **geschnittenes** Brot".

However...

According to [Igor Trost, "Das deutsche Adjektiv"](http://books.google.de/books?id=d4fYvaJbJGIC&lpg=PA302&dq=%22unflektierte%20adjektive%22%20%22sch%C3%B6ner%20land%22&hl=de&pg=PA302#v=onepage&q=%22unflektierte%20adjektive%22%20%22sch%C3%B6ner%20land%22&f=false), in certain idioms, adjectives appear without their appropriate inflectional suffixes:

- wie geschnitten Brot
- kein schöner Land
- auf gut Glück
- etc.

Comment: It's perhaps not immediately obvious to everyone that _schöner_ in _kein schöner Land_ is comparative without inflectional ending, not positive with masculine ending.

Comment: A similar construct can be found in many toponyms, e.g. "Grünwald, Alt Grünwald", "Klein Altgrünwald" etc. (vs. "Grüner Wald", "Altes Grünerwald", "Kleines Altesgrünerwald"...)

Comment: @chirlu It's *completely* non-obvious. I used to think that too, and I *am* German.