# Is it still considered correct to append an "e" in old-fashioned dative?

Tags: dative

I recently watched some shows by Prof. Heinz Haber (1968) and I noticed, that he tends to append an "e" to the dative as in `auf dem Monde` or `im Raume`.

[Udo Klinger](http://www.udoklinger.de/Deutsch/Grammatik/DekNomen.htm) lists the added "e" in parenthesis, which I interpret as "okay, but not necessary".

I suppose it is *not* okay to add an "e" if the noun ends with a vowel. But I am not sure. What are the rules when an extra "e" is okay and when it is not.

In contrast to the already answered question:

[When, if at all, should I add an e to the end of a noun in the dative case?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7906/when-if-at-all-should-i-add-an-e-to-the-end-of-a-noun-in-the-dative-case)

I'd like to know when you *can* add an "e", not when you *have to*.

Comment: Possibly relevant question: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/7906/3407

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Dative-E is considered dated, but you can of course use it. [According to Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ#Dativ-e), it never appears with:

- feminine nouns
- nouns ending on -el, -en, em, -er,
- names or foreign words

Dudengrammatik lists four factors in § 317:

- I) word is part of the basic vocabulary or part of an idiom
- II) exalted speech
- III) nouns which can have a long genitive ending (des Baum*es*)
- IV) the nount has to be preceded by a declinated word, such as an article!

You *should* use it for certain idioms which contain dative case:

> Im Zug*e* dessen
>   Am Tag*e* der Wiedervereinigung
>   Nach dem Tod*e* meines Mannes
>   Im Jahr*e* des Herrn

Comment: Actually, the last three idioms you gave can be written without the -e. It sounds perfectly fine in modern language. Only "Im Zuge dessen" needs the -e because it is a fix phrase.

Comment: I always wondered why the dative of Haus can be written as Hause, but the dative of Maus cannot be written with an added e. "never with feminine nouns" explains that.

Comment: @dervonnebenaan: You're right for Tage/Tode. I consider "Im Jahre des Herrn" fixed as well.