# "Die Liebe höret nimmer auf!"

Tags: expression

I saw today this picture:

[image: Grave stone inscription: 'Die Liebe höret nimmer auf!']

This does not seem to be any verbal form from *aufhören*. What is this expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is actually a form of "aufhören", just a bit old style -   a quotation from the Bible, 1. Korinther,  13:8 (Corinthians 13:8: Love never ends) .

A modern way of saying this sentence is "Die Liebe hört nie auf".

Comment: Am I to understand that is just the old way of writing the present?

Comment: No, it's Präsens.

Comment: I added some info in the answer.

Comment: I think (merely _guess_) "nimmer" is some kind of junction of "nicht immer" (similar to "not ever" vs. "never"). But that's only guesswork and I don't know the proper grammatical terms for such a thing.

Comment: "nimmer"  means "never", "never again " @PerlDuck

Comment: Yes, @Eller, I know, I expressed myself badly. It was just an observation I made. My reasoning was nimmer → nicht immer → not ever → never, thus: nimmer → never.

Comment: @PerlDuck> The problem is that "nicht immer" means "not always", which is completely different from "not ever".

Comment: nicht mehr, nie mehr, nimmer.

Comment: This historical shift is of course similar to that in English: Love never stoppeth.

Answer (score 3):

Up until approximately a century ago, it was common to include much more *e*’s in writing verbs than nowadays. Verb forms that today would be written *Xst* or *Xt*, where *X* is any consonant sound, where often spelt *Xest* or *Xet* instead. In long gone times, there was probably a shwa to separate the consonant cluster which has since been reduced to sheer nothingness. By readding that shwa into one’s spoken language, one can nowadays create a very dated or very religious feeling — the latter because, naturally, many old Bible translations preserved said written *e*. Thus, *höret* is nothing more and nothing less than a dated *spelling* of *hört.* Similarly:

> Gehet hin und mehret euch (old)
> Geht hin und mehrt euch (contemporary spelling but still dated word choice and grammar)
>
> [Wo gehest du hin?](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wo_gehest_du_hin%3F) (old)
> Wo gehst du hin? (contemporary)

---

Likewise, the word *nimmer* is a [dated variant of today’s *nie*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nimmer) although it is also a contemporary southern colloquial form of *nicht mehr/nie mehr.* While your example would make sense using *nicht mehr,* I would assume that the intended meaning is in fact *nie.*

Putting it all together, in contemporary German the grave would read:

> Die Liebe hört nie auf.

In no case has the meaning shifted, only the spelling of one word and the use of the other is dated.

Comment: I disagree with the stated absoluteness, that more *e*s were present earlier. *Meyers Konversationslexikon* from 1892 proves, that adjectives and comparatives had less. It consistently uses *unter anderm*, *größern* and provides many more examples.

Comment: @guidot Interesting point. I was specifically referring to verbs, so I added another *verb*. I hope it’s better now?

Comment: It's surely better, but I had assumed that you also wanted to cover the trailing e in dative case, as discussed [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/7906/1696). Not intended?

Comment: @guidot The dative-*e* is a good point but considering that the question is more on a verb I feel it is okay to restrict the discussion to verbs ;)