# fließend oder fließendes Wasser

Tags: adjective, declension

Ich bin kürzlich über folgenden Satz gestoßen:

> Menschen leben in Wellblechhütten ohne WC und *fließend* Wasser.

Dabei habe ich mich gefragt, ob es nicht eher "fließend**es** Wasser" heißen sollte. In diesem Fall bin ich mir ziemlich sicher, dass "fließend Wasser" kein fixer Ausdruck ist, den man so verwenden kann. Ich denke, man muss das Adjektiv beugen.

---

Weniger sicher bin ich mir bei folgendem Beispiel:

> Im Haus gibt es *fließend* Wasser.

Dieser Satz ist, denke ich, syntaktisch korrekt. Man kann danach fragen:

> "In welcher Art gibt es Wasser im Haus? *Fließend*.

Stellt man allerdings die Frage "Was gibt es im Haus?" Wäre die korrekte Antwort darauf wohl *fließend**es** Wasser*.

---

**Die konkrete Frage ist also**: gehört das Adjektiv im ersten Beispiel gebeugt (*fließend*) oder kann es auch *fließend* bleiben?

Außerdem bitte ich um Korrektur, falls ich in meinem zweiten Beispiel falsch geschlussfolgert habe.

Comment: Beispiel im Duden für fließend Wasser: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Warmwasser

Comment: Genau, in dem Beispiel tritt, denke ich, mein zweiter Fall ein. Da sehe ich auch, dass _fließend Wasser_ syntaktisch auch korrekt ist. Meine Frage bleibt für negative Formulierungen (ohne, kein...) noch offen.

Comment: Verwandte Frage: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/is-wie-geschnitten-brot-grammatically-correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Man versteht unter dem festen Begriff **fließend Wasser** das Wasser, das in einer Wohnung aus dem Wasserhahn fließt. Beugt man *fließend*, dann wird die Bedeutung zu Gunsten der Eigenschaft verschoben, *fließendes Wasser* ist dann wirklich ein fließen, wie in einem Bach oder einer Traufe.

Allerdings finden wir beide Varianten in der Beschreibung der Sanitärinstallation einer Wohnung, so dass man nicht die eine oder die andere Variante als richtiger oder besser bezeichnen kann. Auch im Duden werden Beispiele für beide Varianten gegeben:

> [ein Zimmer mit fließendem Wasser](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wasser)
>   [das Zimmer hat fließend Warmwasser](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Warmwasser)

Interessant ist noch die Beugung, wenn man *fließend* und *warm* zusammen bringen möchte:

> 1. Das Zimmer hat fließend warmes Wasser.
>      *Es gibt Warmwasser aus der Leitung.*
> 2. Das Zimmer hat warm fließendes Wasser.
>      *Das Wasser, welches aus der Leitung fließt, ist warm.*
> 3. Das Zimmer hat fließendes warmes Wasser.
>      *Nicht eindeutig, aber tendenziell eher Bedeutung 1.*
> 4. Das Zimmer hat warmes fließendes Wasser.
>      *Wie 3. aber tendenziell eher Bedeutung 2.*

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung. In deinem ersten Block: kann ich also auch genauso korrekt sagen "ein Zimmer mit **fließend** Wasser" und "das Zimmer hat **fließendes** Wasser". Für mich sind die zwei Sätze irgendwie grammatikalisch unterschiedlich zu bewerten...

Comment: @jera: ich denke, beide Varianten sind erlaubt, in jedem Fall ist das ungebeugte *fließend* aber eine grammatikalische Ausnahme.