# Warum heißt der Film "Das radikal Böse" anstatt "Das radikale Böse"?

Tags: adjective, declension, adjective-ending

Es gibt einen Film, der [Das radikal Böse](http://www.dasradikalboese.wfilm.de/Das_Radikal_Bose/Start.html) heißt, und dieser Titel scheint mir falsch zu sein.

Ich denke, dass "radikal" in diesem Fall ein Adjektiv ist, kein Adverb, und deshalb sollte es "radikale" heißen. Ich kann aber nicht glauben, dass der Titel einen Fehler beinhaltet!

Ist der Titel also richtig? Und warum?

EDIT: Dieser Fall scheint mir anders zu sein als "[wie geschnitten Brot](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/is-wie-geschnitten-brot-grammatically-correct)". Wie die Antwort zu jener Frage erklärt, geht es um einen grammatischen Fehler, der aber bei einigen Ausdrücken ausnahmsweise korrekt ist. Hier ist die Sache anders.

Comment: Maybe it is a stylistic device, so it is "wrong" but it's wanted to be so.

Comment: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Adjektiv.html#Anchor-Freie-35326

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is "wie geschnitten Brot" grammatically correct?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/is-wie-geschnitten-brot-grammatically-correct)

Comment: @mle no, it's not. Grammatically entirely different form

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kommt darauf an, was man qualifizieren will - es kann beides richtig sein. Nehmen wir ein anderes Beispiel:

> Die furchtbare Alte (1)

vs.

> Die furchtbar Alte (2)

In (1) bezieht sich das "furchtbar" auf die Frau, sie ist also "alt **und** furchtbar", während sich "furchtbar" in (2) auf "alt" bezieht, sie ist also "furchtbar alt". Wird das erste Adjektiv mit dem substantivierten zweiten Adjektiv flektiert, bezieht es sich auf das Substantiv, also die Frau - Wenn nicht, dient es als Adverb und qualifiziert es die Eigenschaft.

Oder nehmen wir z.B. die *flüchtige Bekannte*, die wir nur mit Hilfe eines Adverbs zu einer *flüchtig Bekannten* machen können und somit vor der Strafverfolgung retten können.

Das Englische unterscheidet strenger zwischen Adjektiven und Adverbien - hier würde (1) als *terrible, old ...* und (2) als *terribly old* geformt.

Comment: Muss der "Alte" in "der furchtbar Alte" nicht zwingend ein Adjektiv sein?

Comment: @Arminius Natürlich ist "alt" ein Adjektiv - Aber hier in der Funktion eines Substantivs.

Comment: Aber gerade da "der Alte" eine Substantivierung ist, hätte ich erwartet, dass ein Adverb davor gar nicht zulässig ist.

Comment: @Arminius warum nicht? Wer bestimmt, wo ein Adverb stehen darf? Es qualifiziert das "alt sein" der Alten. Genauso wie im ursprünglichen Filmtitel das "böse sein" des Bösen durch "radikal" qualifiziert wird.

Comment: Ich hatte erwartet, dass es grammatikalisch nur erlaubt ist, ein eine Eigenschaft qualifizierendes Adverb vor einem echten Adjektiv zu verwenden, nicht aber vor einer Substantivierung. Ich kann diese Annahme aber nicht belegen, von daher brauchen wir keine längere Diskussion daraus zu machen. :)

Comment: @Arminius Die Basisfrage ist, ob das Adjektiv durch die Substantivierung plötzlich alle seine Eigenschaften verliert - Nein, tut es nicht, z.B. kann man es auch in den Komparativ oder Superlativ erheben (*die Ältere*), was man mit einem Substantiv ja auch nicht kann.Von daher spricht auch nichts dagegen, es weiterhin mit einem Adverb zu qualifizieren.

Comment: Trotzdem würde ich von einer flüchtigen Bekannten reden, wohl weil ich *Bekannte* nicht mehr als Substantivierung empfinde und den Ausdruck wie einen *guten Freund* behandle, mit dem ich ja auch gut befreundet bin. Anders wäre es mit einer *mir flüchtig Bekannten*.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich liegt mein Problem daran, dass ich wie ein Italiener denke. Ich wüsste nicht, wie man “Das radikal Böse” ins Italienische übersetzen könnte ("Il radicalmente male"? Es klingt ganz, ganz falsch), wobei "Das radikale Böse" ("Il male radicale") vollkommen richtig ist. Ich sehe die Sache wie @Arminius: Ich verstehe "Die furchtbar alte Frau", wo "alte" ein Adjektiv ist, aber wenn es substantiviert ist, scheint es mir einfach falsch. Tja, ich werde mich daran gewöhnen müssen...

Comment: @FabioTurati: Wie ist es mit "das, was radikal böse ist"? Lässt sich das auch nicht direkt übersetzen? (Unabhängig davon ist auf Deutsch *radikal* keines der Adverbien, die ich selber potenziell wählen würde, um *böse* zu qualifizieren.)

Comment: @CarstenS: "weil ich *Bekannte* nicht mehr als Substantivierung empfinde" - in der Tat hat sich das Substantiv *der/die Bekannte* ja auch in der Bedeutung vom Adjektiv entfernt, da es eben nicht eine generell bekannte Person (Politiker, Schauspieler usw.) bezeichnet, sondern speziell jemanden aus dem Bekanntenkreis einer im Kontext eindeutigen Person.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Es ist besser, obwohl ich auf Italienisch zwei verschiedene Worte für das Substantiv und für das Adjektiv benutzen würde. Aber in diesem Fall klingt mir der Satz vollkommen richtig, sowohl auf Deutsch als auch auf Italienisch, was ich für den originalen Titel nicht sagen kann.

Answer (score 3):

> Das wirklich Schöne ist, dass beides möglich ist.

Deutsch ist mit seinen Adverben sehr nachlässig. Tatsächlich kann man praktisch überall ein adverbial gebrauchtes Adjektiv setzen. Die beiden Worte funktionieren dann wie ein Eigenname.

> Das radikal Böse hat wieder zugeschlagen.

Eine Bande oder Kraft mit diesem Namen.

> Das radikale Böse hat wieder zugeschlagen.

Und das nichtradikale Böse?

> Zwei radikal Böse haben wieder zugeschlagen.

"Radikal Böse" ist der vom Sprecher einer Gruppe zugewiesene Name.

> Zwei radikale Böse haben wieder zugeschlagen.

Zwei einzelne Böse, die außerdem noch radikal sind.